# Issue posting Form within iframe in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I have a web page embedded as a form within an iFrame.

The web page posts back using the following javascript code triggered from an anchor tag

```
function GoToPdf(link) {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.action = link;
    form.target = "_blank";
    form.method = "Post";
    form.submit();
}
```

The link passed is an .aspx page that retrieves JSON data passed in the request body and creates a PDF for download.

The whole thing works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE 11. If the web page is outside of an iFrame it also works on IE 11.

In the iframe on IE 11 the page posts back to the .aspx page but the request body contains no data.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a security issue. Try adding the domain you are trying to access to your IE trusted zone.

Comment: If I add in the web page domain that is used in the iFrame to the Trusted Sites it works, so yes thanks for that. However the client is not happy with this as a solution. What is needed is a way to solve it in code so the user does not have to change default browser settings.